# How to add second level footer in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, footer

Added container in default.xml within footer container

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container">
            <container name="em.maxwidth.content" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="em-maxwidth-content" before="-"/>
            <container name="footer" as="footer" label="Page Footer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer_second">
                <container name="als-footer-container" label="Als Footer Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container" before="-"> //add container 
              </container>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
```

after that create a block and assign block and that block assign to widget with a new container.

But it did not add second level footer.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your container is empty, when a container is empty it is ignored.

Add a block that outputs something and your container should display.

Also, `als-footer-container` does not have a closing tag.

Comment: Hi I have assigned a block to this container and i have also closed this container

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra container in footer using the following piece of XML.

```
<referenceContainer name="footer">
    <container name="secondfooter" label="Second Footer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="secondfooter content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_footer_block" template="Magento_Theme::custom_footer.phtml" />
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: i tried this but its not working for me

Comment: It worked on my end. Please double check your filename and other data.

Comment: let's me check once again